# How to fetch the list of files from an android app from the server using php?

Tags: php, android, httprequest, httpresponse

I am working on the *server side* of a software development intern team and I am asked to **fetch** a list of files present in an **android app/device**. 
We are using **PHP** as the server-side scripting language. How do I send such a request?
Also, will its response be an HTTP get/post request; if so, how to save that data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't fetch list of files from server,the app have to send you the list of files over http via get or post and you have to accept it and and update the response on your end

Comment: @PramodYadav - Okay, so the android app sends the list of files via get/post request and I receive it using php $_POST right ?

Comment: at server side you have to recieve that request how to receive a request in php i don't know as i am an android guy